# Change the ripple of the IconButton

Tags: android, android-studio, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-button

how I can fix this

[image]
[image]

```
@Composable
fun Body() {

    val scrollState = rememberScrollState()

    Column(
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(10.dp),
        modifier = Modifier
            .verticalScroll(state = scrollState)
            .fillMaxSize()
            .padding(top = 10.dp)
    ) {

        //....

        Surface(
            color = Color.LightGray,
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth(0.95f),
            shape = RoundedCornerShape(CornerSize(10.dp)),
            elevation = 1.dp,
        ) {

            var expanded by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

            Column(
                verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(5.dp)
            ) {

                Row(
                    verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
                ) {

                    //....

                    IncrementDecrementButton()
                }

                //...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I use `.offset` to reduce the spaces between the buttons and the text

```
@Composable
fun IncrementDecrementButton() {

    var Number by remember { mutableStateOf(1) }

    IconButton(onClick = { Number += 1 }) {
        Icon(
            imageVector = Icons.Default.Add,
            contentDescription = "",
            modifier = Modifier
                .size(20.dp)
                .offset(x = 10.dp)
        )
    }

    Text(
        text = "$Number",
        modifier = Modifier
            .size(20.dp),
        textAlign = TextAlign.Center
    )

    IconButton(
        onClick = {
            if (Number > 1)
                Number -= 1
        }
    ) {
        Icon(
            painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_baseline_remove_24),
            contentDescription = "",
            modifier = Modifier
                .size(20.dp)
                .offset(x = (-10).dp)
        )
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Do you want the click animation to be non-borderless?

Comment: i want the animation to be in central 
also smaller if it's possible

Comment: It's not in the center because you are offsetting the icons. Remove the offsets and use `padding` modifier if you need margin between the icon and text.

Answer (score 2):

The animation is the ripple related to the IconButton but you can't change the radius of the `Ripple` since it is embedded inside the `IconButton`.

If you want to change the dimension of the `IconButton`, you can use something like:

```
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .padding(1.dp)
            .size(20.dp)
            .clickable(
                onClick = { Number += 1 },
                enabled = enabled,
                interactionSource = interactionSource,
                indication = rememberRipple(bounded = false, radius = 10.dp)
            ),
        contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
    ) {
        val contentAlpha = if (enabled) LocalContentAlpha.current else ContentAlpha.disabled
        CompositionLocalProvider(LocalContentAlpha provides contentAlpha){
            Icon(
                imageVector = Icons.Default.Add,
                contentDescription = "",
            )
        }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Yep, so strange.. why comopose-material team base ripple on IconButtonTokens.StateLayerSize / 2 (where StateLayerSize = 40.0.dp) 
It's will be better to use the actual size of the button.. or simmply to add a parameter for ripple radius